# Surface Integral of a paraboloid below a plane

Tags: integration, surface-integrals, parametrization

I'm trying to solve this problem:

> Considering S the part of the paraboloid $z=x^{2}+y^{2}$ that is underneath the plane $z=3-2y$, calculate the integral:
>
> $$\int\int_{S}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+4z}}dS.$$

I have tried to use parametrization and the formula
$$\iint\limits_{S}{{f\left( {x,y,z} \right)\,dS}} = \iint\limits_{D}{{f\left( {\vec r\left( {u,v} \right)} \right)\left\| {{{\vec r}_u} \times {{\vec r}_v}} \right\|\,dA}}$$

but I couldn't get anywhere. I believe I'm doing something wrong because I get that
$$ \iint\limits_{D}{{f\left( {\vec r\left( {u,v} \right)} \right)\left\| {{{\vec r}_u} \times {{\vec r}_v}} \right\|\,dA}}=\iint 1 dA.$$ It would be of great appreciation if someone could help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\displaystyle \iint_{S}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+4z}} \ dS$

Surface $S$ is $z = x^2+y^2$, bound above by plane $z = 3 - 2y$

Now we know that,

$\displaystyle \iint_{S}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+4z}} \ dS = \iint_{E}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+4z}} \sqrt{1+ \bigg(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\bigg)^2 + \bigg(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\bigg)^2} \ \ dA$

where $E$ is the projection of the surface in $XY$ plane and $dA$ is the area element of the projection.

This indeed simplifies to $\displaystyle \iint_{E} 1 \cdot dA$

Now to find projection of the surface in $XY$ plane,

$z = x^2+y^2 = 3 - 2y \implies x^2+(y+1)^2 = 4$

We substitute $x = r \cos\theta, y = -1 + r\sin\theta$ and we have $0 \leq r \leq 2, 0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$

So the integral becomes $\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^2 r \ dr \ d\theta = 4 \pi$

Comment: If you want to use $|r'_u \times r'_v|$, parametrize the surface as $r(u, v) = (u \cos v, -1 + u \sin v, u^2 - 2 u \sin v + 1), 0 \leq u \leq 2, 0 \leq v \leq 2\pi$. It will simplify and you will get the same integral.